# excel - if and statement inside an iferror with index small row nest

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am new with Excel and everything I have learned is through researching forums.

My goal is to build a form letter that pulls data from my tables and populates relevant information for several projects - so far everything is working fine

I have the following working formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(LI_Input[LI],SMALL(IF($B$4=LI_Input[Grab File],ROW(LI_Input[Grab File])-MIN(ROW(LI_Input[Grab File]))+1,""),ROW(A2))),"")
```

This pulls all the phone numbers attached to a sub project($B$4)

What I would like to do is add an AND statement to add a condition that pulls  only phone numbers that belong to a phone company (Verison, Sprint, etc... located in cell b2) along with the

This is one of the variation I have tried but no results display

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(LI_Input[LI],SMALL(IF(AND($B$4=LI_Input[Grab File],B2=LI_Input[Provider LI 1]),ROW(LI_Input[Grab File])-MIN(ROW(LI_Input[Grab File])))+1,""),ROW(A1)),"")
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Array formula do not work with `AND` or `OR`.  Use `*` or `+` respectively as replacements.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(LI_Input[LI],SMALL(IF(($B$4=LI_Input[Grab File])*(B2=LI_Input[Provider LI 1]),ROW(LI_Input[Grab File])-MIN(ROW(LI_Input[Grab File])))+1,""),ROW(A1)),"")
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `[]` around the formula.

Comment: I used the + and it solved the problem (You are a genius - Thank you)

Comment: @RobbG the `+` is the same as `OR` not `AND`.  To do `And` you need to do the `*`.  Also please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.